# tcl - insert characters and replace lines

Tags: join, foreach, insert, tcl, overwrite

Say I ask tcl to print the following from within nested dictionary (containing rows and columns) - Reference: Brad Lanam

```
set id0 "[dict values [dict get $risedata constraints constraint $c 0]]"
```

...and I get this

```
1.1 2.1 3.1 4.1 5.1
```

Now I wish to change

`{1.1 2.1 3.1 4.1 5.1}` to get `{"1.1,2.1,3.1,4.1,5.1", \}`

By adding the

1) ',' in between the values
2) ',' space and ' \' at the end
3) " at the start

I know I have to use join and linsert (I did join and need help with linsert)

1) ATTEMPT: `set id0 [join $id0 ","]` to get `1.1,2.1,3.1,4.1,5.1`

2) QUESTION: How do I convert `1.1,2.1,3.1,4.1,5.1` to `{"1.1,2.1,3.1,4.1,5.1", \}`

I tried `set id0 [linsert [linsert $id0 end , "] 1 "]` but it is INCORRECT. Please help!

Ok so after that is done I want to

... write the line (`{"1.1,2.1,3.1,4.1,5.1", \}`) over (overwrite) line 1 under 'values' which is `"1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5", \` in this file format (called liberty (z.lib) - used for chip design). All other lines (rise_constraint ... etc) should be printed as is.

Snippet of z.lib

```
rise_constraint (constraint_template_5X5) {  
  index_1 ("0.01, 0.75, 0.72, 0.9, 0.8");  
  index_2 ("0.075, 0.025, 0.04, 0.3, 0.8");  
  index_3 ("0.084, 0.83, 3.99, 8.1, 19.44") ;  
  values ( \  
    "1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5", \        
    "2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5", \  
    "3.1,3.2,3.3,3.4,3.5", \  
    "4.1,4.2,4.3,4.4,4.5", \ 
    "5.1,5.2,5.3,5.4,5.5", \  
  );  
}
```

Note: I understand that For writing out a file, one would use open, close, dict, foreach, puts - to overwrite multiple lines (in this case 5 lines of 'values') - As wellexplained by Brad Lanam in a previous tcl query.

How do we use a foreach loop to iterate over 5 lines (in my .lib file format) and change it to my dict returned values???

Greatly appreciate your help on this!! Thank you so much! I'm a graduate student.

Reference: Brad Lanam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use [`format`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/format.htm) here:

```
set id0 [list 1.1 2.1 3.1 4.1 5.1]
set str [format "\"%s\" \\" [join $id0 ,]]
puts $str
```

```
"1.1,2.1,3.1,4.1,5.1" \
```

Comment: Brilliant!! That was very slick! Thanks. If you really don't mind, do you know how I can use a foreach loop to replace the 5 old strings (under values) with the formatted strings? How can I read my z.lib file,  search for the keyword 'values' and replace the strings effectively. I really appreciate your advice.

Comment: Do you know how to also include a ',' (comma) right after the last double-quote in the line (using format)? So "1.1,2.1,3.1,4.1,5.1", \ as opposed to "1.1,2.1,3.1,4.1,5.1" \
Thanks so much!

Comment: How do you think you will have to alter `format`'s first parameter to add that comma?

Comment: It would be set str [format "\"%s\", \\" [join $id0 ,]]

Comment: Your link to format helped. Didn't check that before. Might you be able help in the foreach issue I'm running into. I know how to read the file (set fh [open "C:/Tcl/official/original_snippet.lib" r]) but how do I zero in on values of "rise_constraint" (contained amongst 1000's of other lines) and do line by line replacement of values with newly formatted strings? I'd be indebted for your advice. I imagine the format would be something like this 

set data [split $fh "\n"]
     foreach line $data {
          # do some line processing here
     }

Comment: @edaloke Tcl's `format` is just like C's `sprintf()` except not broken or insecure. And it avoids the things that are just never a good idea at all (or meaningless in Tcl, such as the addresses of things).

Comment: And for mere _thousands_ of lines (i.e., maybe a megabyte of data?) just reading it all in and using the right search is quite good enough. There's a few searching options, depending on _exactly_ what you are doing.

Comment: @edaloke, I got generous and added an answer to your original question